# ui-router - passing promise result to nested resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-router

I've ui-router with nested resolve like this :

```
    $stateProvider
         .state('route', {
             url: '/route',
             templateUrl: 'mypage.aspx',
             resolve: {
                 getjson: function (readJson,$http) {
                     var readjsonget = $http.get('files.json');
                     readjsonget.then(function (result) {
                         return result.data;                             
                     }, function (ex) {
                         console.log('GET error', ex);
                     });                         
                 },
                 load: function ($q, filesInject, getjson) {
                     files = getjson;
                     $log.info(2);
                     return $q.all(files.map(filesInject.inject));
                 }
             }
         })
```

I read a json and I want to pass the content to the second resolve function.

I've tried many ways but always the promise success is fired after the second function.

How can I solve this?

Comment: for example: move this to service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a return to the promise readjsonget.

```
$stateProvider
     .state('route', {
         url: '/route',
         templateUrl: 'mypage.aspx',
         resolve: {
             getjson: function (readJson, $http) {
                 var readjsonget = $http.get('files.json');
                 return readjsonget.then(function (result) {
                     return result.data;                             
                 }, function (ex) {
                     console.log('GET error', ex);
                 });                         
             },
             load: function ($q, filesInject, getjson) {
                 files = getjson;
                 $log.info(2);
                 return $q.all(files.map(filesInject.inject));
             }
         }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
   $stateProvider
     .state('route', {
         url: '/route',
         templateUrl: 'mypage.aspx',
         resolve: {
             getjson: function (readJson,$http) {
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 var readjsonget = $http.get('files.json');
                 readjsonget.then(function (result) {
                     deferred.resolve(result);          
                 }, function (ex) {
                     deferred.reject(ex);
                 });          
                 return deferred.promise;               
             },
             load: function ($q, filesInject, getjson) {
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 files = getjson;
                 $log.info(2);
                 files.then(function(data){
                     deferred.resolve(data.map(mapFunction));
                 }, function(error){
                     deferred.reject(error);
                 });
                 return deferred.promise;
             }
         }
     })
```